# How to use tree traversal to upload folders and files into database

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, backend, q

Hey everyone I have this data and using this I want to create folders and files in mysql database.

I currently have two tables one for files and one for folders, both of these tables have a property called `parent_id` which stores the parent id of the file or the folder.

all of these files have been uploaded and are stored in the database already but I want to update their `parent_id` and also create folders using the `original_path`. To do that I need to access the insertIds when we create folders.

```js
[ { filename: 'videoplayback.mp4',
    file_id: '75f6d49e60ee472086d6d59220a203e69f797179',
    user_id: 1825874,
    original_path: 'test folder/child 2/child 3/videoplayback.mp4' },
  { filename: 'gcp2.mp4',
    file_id: 'c719eb645a144ab3ac93acd963b343574b59f94d',
    user_id: 1825874,
    original_path: 'test folder/child 2/gcp2.mp4' },
  { filename: 'video file.mp4',
    file_id: '4f7cc6094c6549d0afe5df18f502a19534767f33',
    user_id: 1825874,
    original_path: 'test folder/video file.mp4' },
  { filename: 'gcp.mp4',
    file_id: 'a735eeef15bb4a839624e3af5058897617752d3e',
    user_id: 1825874,
    original_path: 'test folder/child 1/gcp.mp4' } ]
```

Right now I have this function called `makeTree` which converts this array into a tree like structure using the original_path and return it.

```js
var make_tree = (files) => {
        var tree = {};
        var filesArray = Array.from(files);
      
        var addPath = (file, tree, user_id, file_id) => {
            if (file.original_path.endsWith(".DS_Store")) return;
            var path = file.original_path;
          
            // helper function to create child objects
            var createChild = (name, user_id, file_id) => ({
              name,
              user_id,
              children: [],
              ...(file_id !== undefined && { file_id }), // add file_id only if it's defined and is the last child
            });
          
            // split path to array of folders and files
            var parts = path.split("/");
          
            // create tree if empty
            if (!tree.name) {
              var otherFile = filesArray.find((f) => f.original_path !== path);
              var user_id = otherFile ? otherFile.user_id : undefined;
              Object.assign(tree, createChild(parts[0], user_id, undefined));
            }
          
            parts.shift();
          
            // check and add other path parts
            let isLastChild = false;
            parts.reduce((current, part, index) => {
              isLastChild = index === parts.length - 1; // check if this is the last child
              var child = current.children.find((child) => child.name === part);
          
              if (child) {
                return child;
              }
          
              var newChild = createChild(part, user_id, isLastChild ? file_id : undefined); // pass file_id only if it's the last child
              current.children.push(newChild);
              return newChild;
            }, tree);
          };
      
        filesArray.forEach((file) => addPath(file, tree, file.user_id, file.file_id));
        return tree;
    };
```

when I pass the data in this function, the function returns this data structure

```js
{
  name: "test folder",
  user_id: 1825874,
  children: [
    {
      name: "child 2",
      user_id: 1825874,
      children: [
        {
          name: "child 3",
          user_id: 1825874,
          children: [
            {
              name: "videoplayback.mp4",
              user_id: 1825874,
              children: [],
              file_id: "2cef9d399c994973bf7b739841c1268de0d14aa7"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "gcp2.mp4",
          user_id: 1825874,
          children: [],
          file_id: "6ab41ebbacb546d89a97c4977bbcac8e9004b8c0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "video file.mp4",
      user_id: 1825874,
      children: [],
      file_id: "062b6da1e14445fc95259d060c0d0f4273f33d9e"
    },
    {
      name: "child 1",
      user_id: 1825874,
      children: [
        {
          name: "gcp.mp4",
          user_id: 1825874,
          children: [],
          file_id: "8b2acac9c8514b14be93661725863f2448a89af4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now using this data I'm running this code to insert the folder and files into the database but this code is wrong (Provided only for reference)

```js
// The folder parameter is the tree that we got from the "makeTree" function.
// parent_id is the parent_id of the root folder.
// the callback runs at the end of the function because I invoke this function using Q.nfcall()

var process_zip_folders = function(folder, parent_id, callback) {
        var mysql = null;
        var query = '';

        Q.fcall(function () {
            return Q.ninvoke(cgws, "mysqlConnection");

        }).then(function (value) {
            mysql = value;

            //inserting the root folder into the database 
            query = "INSERT INTO cgws_folders (name, parent_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            return Q.ninvoke(mysql, "query", query, [folder.name, parent_id, folder.user_id]);

        }).then(function(value){
            var info = value[1];
            var parent_id = info.insertId;
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            var child_index = 0;
            var depth_index = 0;
            var child_ids = {};
            var children = [];
            var isLastDepth = true;

            var cb_process_children = function(err){
                if(err){
                    return deferred.reject(err);
                }

                for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
                    if(children[i].children.length > 0){
                        isLastDepth = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(isLastDepth){
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    child_index = 0;

                    children = children[depth_index++].children;

                    setImmediate(function(){
                        process_children(child_ids[parent_id][child_index], cb_process_children);
                    });
                }
            }

            var process_child = function(child, parent_id, callback){
                var query = '';

                if(!child){
                    return callback();
                }

                if (child.file_id) {
                    query = "UPDATE cgws_files SET parent_id=? WHERE file_id=?";
                    mysql.query(query, [parent_id, child.file_id], function(err){
                        if(err){
                            return callback(err);
                        }
                        callback();
                    });
                } else {
                    query = "INSERT INTO cgws_folders (name, parent_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                    mysql.query(query, [child.name, parent_id, child.user_id], function (err, result, info) {
                        if (err) {
                            return callback(err);
                        }

                        callback(null, info.insertId);
                    });
                }
            }
    
            var process_children = function(parent_id, callback){
                var child = children[child_index];
                var cb_process_child = function(err, child_id){

                    if(err){
                        return callback(err);
                    }

                    if(!child_ids[parent_id]){
                        child_ids[parent_id] = []; 
                    }

                    child_ids[parent_id].push(child_id);

                    if(++child_index < children.length){
                        setImmediate(function(){
                            process_child(children[child_index], parent_id, cb_process_child);
                        });
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
    
                process_child(child, parent_id, cb_process_child)
            };

            children = folder.children;

            process_children(parent_id, cb_process_children);

            return deferred.promise;

        }).then(function(){
            callback();

        }).fail(function(error){
            cgws.logError(error)

        }).fin(function () {
            if (mysql) {
                mysql.end()
            }
        })
    };
```

You can either use the converted tree structure or simply the raw data from the array to make this work.

Thanks :)